# Calculate the displacement coordinates of a semi-articulated truck

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

As shown in the image below, I'm creating a program that will make a 2D animation of a truck that is made up of two articulated parts.

[image]

The truck pulls the trailer.

The trailer moves according to the docking axis on the truck.

Then, when the truck turns, the trailer should gradually align itself with the new angle of the truck, as it does in real life.

I would like to know if there is any formula or algorithm that does this calculation in an easy way.

I've already seen inverse kinematics equations, but I think for just 2 parts it would not be so complex.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Yes, they are called the *equations of motion*. You can consider the tractor and trailer as separate Cartesian vectors joined at the docking axis. The angle between the tractor and trailer as a function of time will depend on the forces on each (e.g. the force imparted by the frictional forces between the tires and road -- which ell depend on the velocity and the amount of steering input). There is no magic, The sum of the forces will equal Ma and the sum of the moments will equal I(alpha). It's simply a dynamics problem for you to model.

Comment: Also consider [*Euler's equations (rigid body dynamics)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics))

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I may be wrong, but right now I'm not concerned with physics (mass, torque, inertia), but I think this is just a matter of basic geometry. There are two connected axes where the displacement of the first influence of the POSITION of the other axis.

Comment: I was wondering is there was a way to model this movement, not with equations of motion, but with a constrained system. Maybe something akin to a stick figure where the movement of a bone is transmitted to the next bones in the tree via a joint.

Answer (score 3):

Let `A` be the midpoint under the front axle, `B` be the midpoint under the middle axle, and `C` be the midpoint under the rear axle.  For simplicity assume that the hitch is at point `B`.  These are all functions of time `t`, for example `A(t) = (a_x(t), a_y(t)`.

The trick is this.  `B` is moving directly towards `A` with the component of `A`'s velocity in that direction.  Or in symbols, `dB/dt = (dA/dt).(A-B)/||A-B||`  And similarly, `dC/dt = (dB/dt).(B-C)/||B-C||` where `.` is the dot product.

This turns into a non-linear first-order system in 6 variables.  This can be solved with normal techniques, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods.

**UPDATE:** Added code

Here is a Python implementation.  You can replace it with https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method for your favorite language and your favorite linear algebra library.  Or even hand-roll that.

For my example I started with `A` at `(1, 1)`, `B` at `(2, 1)` and `C` at `(2, 2)`.  Then pulled `A` to the origin in steps of size `0.01`.  That can be altered to anything that you want.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy

# Runga Kutta method.
def RK4(f):
    return lambda t, y, dt: (
            lambda dy1: (
            lambda dy2: (
            lambda dy3: (
            lambda dy4: (dy1 + 2*dy2 + 2*dy3 + dy4)/6
            )( dt * f( t + dt  , y + dy3   ) )
            )( dt * f( t + dt/2, y + dy2/2 ) )
            )( dt * f( t + dt/2, y + dy1/2 ) )
            )( dt * f( t       , y         ) )


# da is a function giving velocity of a at a time t.
# The other three are the positions of the three points.
def calculate_dy (da, A0, B0, C0):
    l_ab = float(numpy.linalg.norm(A0 - B0))
    l_bc = float(numpy.linalg.norm(B0 - C0))

    # t is time, y = [A, B, C]
    def update (t, y):
        (A, B, C) = y
        dA = da(t)

        ab_unit = (A - B) / float(numpy.linalg.norm(A-B))
        # The first term is the force.  The second is a correction to
        # cause roundoff errors in length to be selfcorrecting.
        dB = (dA.dot(ab_unit) + float(numpy.linalg.norm(A-B))/l_ab - l_ab) * ab_unit

        bc_unit = (B - C) / float(numpy.linalg.norm(B-C))
        # The first term is the force.  The second is a correction to
        # cause roundoff errors in length to be selfcorrecting.
        dC = (dB.dot(bc_unit) + float(numpy.linalg.norm(B-C))/l_bc - l_bc) * bc_unit

        return numpy.array([dA, dB, dC])

    return RK4(update)

A0 = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0])
B0 = numpy.array([2.0, 1.0])
C0 = numpy.array([2.0, 2.0])
dy = calculate_dy(lambda t: numpy.array([-1.0, -1.0]), A0, B0, C0)

t, y, dt = 0., numpy.array([A0, B0, C0]), .02
while t <= 1.01:
    print( (t, y) )
    t, y = t + dt, y + dy( t, y, dt )
```

Comment: I did a simple simulation of A, B and C in Geogebra: [link](https://ggbm.at/cw4vw3ZV). Just to normalize the understanding, segment A->B is the truck and segment B->C is the trailer, right? If the truck (A->B) moves for example sqrt(2) centimeters (1.41 cm) at the 225 degree angle as in the example, A will be (0,0) and B will (2,2). But what will be the coordinates of C?

Comment: @RogérioDec I would have to solve the full problem myself to give you an answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks, don't need, even because your formula did not solve this problem, but just that inverse kinematics formula.

Comment: @RogérioDec I'd be willing to bet you $1000 on that.  I gave you the correct formula.  When you use a standard numerical technique like https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method you get an iterative solution.

Comment: After studying your article a little, I definitely doubt that your formula works in this case, since it does not use any trigonometric function for the angular calculations. What's the magic?

Comment: @RogérioDec The magic is that `v . w = ||v|| * || w|| * cos(angle between v and w)`.  I added an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

By the answers I saw, I realized that the solution is not really simple and will have to be solved by an Inverse Kinematics algorithm.

[This site](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/analytic-two-bone-ik-in-2d/) is an example and it is a just a start, although it still does not solve everything, since the point C is fixed and in the case of the truck it should move.

Comment: In the case of the truck the tires also should not slide sideways.  Which means that you have to divide the force into that pulling forwards, and that turning the vehicle.  Which makes the equations into what I gave in my answer.

Comment: I'm not an math expert, but thank you for your tip. I will study this article and try to apply it in practice to see how to solve it. Of course if you gave me the solution, it would be much better, but I have seen that this is not the didactic preferred by mathematicians, who prefer to say: study and get by...

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Analytic Two-Bone IK in 2D article](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/analytic-two-bone-ik-in-2d/), I made a [fully functional model in Geogebra](https://ggbm.at/gpfZqnTC), where the nucleus consists of two simple mathematical equations.